# How can i get all possible combinations of football games in Javascript

Tags: combinations

Assuming you have an array of n games, I want to write a script that receives the number of games being played and returns a multidimensional array of all possible combinations.

Keep in mind that a game can either end in Home Win (1), draw (0) or Away Win (-1).

Example

When n = 2, 
Games    Outcomes

Game 1 => Q vs B: - Q wins (1) - Draw (0) - B Wins (-1)
Game 2 => C vs D: - C Wins (1) - Draw (0) - D wins (-1)

When given 2 games, you will end up with the following combinations:

{1,1}

{1,0}

{1,-1}

{0,1}

{0,0}

{-1,1}

{-1,0}

{-1,-1}

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an equivalent in Java. I know this is an interview question for Infama Limited Kenya

`package com.oluoch.code;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TWODArray {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arr[][] = { { 1, 1 }, { 1, 0 }, { 1, -1 }, { 0, 1 }, { 0, 0 }, { -1, 1 }, { -1, 0 }, { -1, -1 } };

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)

    {

        for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j)

            System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");

    }
}
```

}
`